# Problem to install EasyCam

Tags: webcam, software-installation

I had problem when I install the Easy Cam

```
vitor@vitor-hp:~$ gksudo 'python /usr/share/EasyCam2/core.py --gtk'
vitor@vitor-hp:~$ kdesudo 'python /usr/share/EasyCam2/core.py --qt'
python: can't open file '/usr/share/EasyCam2/core.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

According the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EasyCam) I done all the steps.

Comment: What do you want this program for, can you say what you want to do with the camera, perhaps there is alternate software that will work. Also list what make/model your note book is so we can see if your camera is comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These instructions are only applicable for a previous release of Ubuntu. If you are not using Ubuntu Hardy Heron (8.04), **these instructions will not work.**

The documentation is obsolete. If `/usr/share/EasyCam2/core.py` exist at all after your installation you may be able to use:

```
sudo python /usr/share/EasyCam2/core.py --gtk
```

instead.

Comment: Ok, but how can I use my cam from notebook?